# How to keep downloading N number of files and do further processing as soon as the download is finished?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await

I have to download around 5k zip files. Further, they have to be extracted and processed(they are raster images and will be clipped further). In order to process them faster I thought I can use async.
I would like to achieve the following:

1. Keep downloading N files at the same time (always); further processing should not stop downloading
2. As soon as one file is finished downloading go further doing extraction and raster processing (not implemented yet), while keeping downloading N number of files.

My code:

```
async def zip_extract(data, extracted_dir):
global extracted_orders
with zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(data)) as zip_ref:
# with zipfile.ZipFile(data, 'r') as zip_ref:    
    zip_ref.extractall(extracted_dir)
    extracted_orders += 1 
    print(f'Extracted orders  {extracted_orders}')

sema = asyncio.Semaphore(5)
timeout = aiohttp.ClientTimeout(
    total=600
)
async def fetch_file(session, url, name):
    global all_downloaded_orders
    global save_dir
    global zip_dir
    global async_engine
    # generate path to save
    # filename = os.path.join(save_dir, name.replace('/', '_'))
    order_id = name.split('/')[0]
    while True:

        try:
            # download with semaphore
            async with sema:
                async with session.get(url) as resp:                
                    assert resp.status == 200
                    print(f"Downloading {order_id}")
                    data = await resp.read()
                    all_downloaded_orders += 1
                    print(f"Downloaded {order_id}")
            # generate path to store extracted data
            zip_folder = name.replace('/' , '_').split('_km_')[-1].split('.zip')[0]    
            extracted_dir = os.path.join(zip_dir,zip_folder )
            print(f"Extracting {order_id}")
            await zip_extract(data, extracted_dir)
            print(f"Extracted {order_id}")

            qry_txt = f"""update agro.orders set status = 'extracted' where order_id = '{order_id}' """
            async with async_engine.connect() as conn:
                # select a Result, which will be delivered with buffered
                # results
                result = await conn.execute(text(qry_txt))
            print(f"finished {order_id}")
            
            break
        except Exception as e:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            print(e)

async def main_download(urls):
    global async_engine
    async_engine = db.db_engine_async('planet')
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(timeout = timeout) as session:
        tasks = [fetch_file(session, url, name) for url, name in urls.items()]
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    await async_engine.dispose()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main_download(urls_names))
loop.close()
```

This code is working but not expected. It starts downloading after `print(f"finished {order_id}")`, while the download must start as soon as `print(f"Downloaded {order_id}")` reached.

What should I change in my code?